# Sqlite - How to i query like call log if there is same number continue get as single record with continuously record count only?

Tags: android, sql, database, gaps-and-islands

```
UniqueID | MobileNumber | createDate
-----------+---------+-----+------------+-----------
U_23121  | 987654        | 2013-02-05 
U_23124  | 987654        | 2013-02-02 
U_23122  | 845263        | 2013-01-18 
U_23128  | 654789        | 2013-01-16 
U_23123  | 735689        | 2013-01-12 
U_23128  | 654789        | 2013-01-11 
U_23128  | 654789        | 2013-01-10 
U_23126  | 987654        | 2013-01-09 
U_23125  | 845263        | 2013-01-07 
U_23126  | 845263        | 2013-01-06 
U_23125  | 987654        | 2013-01-05
```

I want to record like filtering with mobile number if more then one continue get latest based on createdDate and get count for that like

```
        UniqueID | Mobile_Number | createDate   | count
        -----------+---------+-----+------------+-----------
        U_23121  | 987654        | 2013-02-05   | 2
        U_23122  | 845263        | 2013-01-18   | 1
        U_23128  | 654789        | 2013-01-16   | 1
        U_23123  | 735689        | 2013-01-12   | 1
        U_23128  | 654789        | 2013-01-11   | 2
        U_23126  | 987654        | 2013-01-09   | 1
        U_23125  | 845263        | 2013-01-07   | 2
        U_23125  | 987654        | 2013-01-05   | 1
```

I'll get record that is need from following query but not getting count

```
SELECT te.*
FROM tableName as te
WHERE te.Mobile_Number <> (select Mobile_Number 
                           from tableName
                           where createDate > te.createDate
                           limit 1
                          )
ORDER BY te.createDate DESC
```

Comment: its mysql or sqlite? these are different DBMS. If it is a mysql then write the version you are using. I have changed the tags.

Comment: @RadimBača is SQLITE

Comment: and which version of sqlite? do you have 3.25 or more?

Comment: is query needs for android SQLITE db so maybe it's not effect versions.

Comment: can you test `select row_number() over (order by createdate) from tablename` query in your db?

Comment: am confused about how i used row_number() as per my table.

Comment: It is not straightforward. The row_number is working for you? I mean the row_number is supported?

Comment: yes row_number supported sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One solution is to assign a "grp" to each row and then aggregate by that group.

You can assign the grp by counting the number of mobile numbers that are *different* from the mobile number in each row, up to that row.  This is a constant value for adjacent mobile numbers.

The resulting query:

```
SELECT MAX(UniqueId), MobileNumber,
       MAX(createDate), COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT te.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM tableName te2
              WHERE te2.createDate < te.createDate AND
                    te2.MobileNumber <> te.MobileNumber
             ) as grp
      FROM tableName te
     ) te
GROUP BY MobileNumber, grp;
ORDER BY MIN(tcreateDate) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the gaps and islands problem. If your Sqllite supports the `row_number` function (version 3.25 and more) then you can use the following approach

```
select MobileNumber, max(createDate), count(*)
from
(
  select *,
       row_number() over (order by createDate) -
       row_number() over (partition by MobileNumber order by createDate) grp
  from data
) t
group by grp, MobileNumber
```

Comment: there is error with your query near "(" can u run query ?

Comment: I've tested only on the PostgreSQL, however, it should work if your sqlite support `row_number`. Can you try to run only the subquery `t` and let me know?

Answer (score -1):

USE GROUP BY

```
SELECT te.* FROM tableName as te where te.Mobile_Number != (select Mobile_Number from tableName where createDate > te.createDate limit 1) GROUP BY Mobile_Number  ORDER BY te.createDate DESC
```

Comment: group by combine all same Mobile_Number record i'll want to combine if there is next is same as per date, please see question and example that i provide. Thanks  @Ram